# Visual studio 2013 peek not dismissing with the Escape key

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Gday.

In Visual Studio 2013 I was using the Peek to definition with much gusto until one day I updated to Update 2. Then it became annoying to use since Update 2 I can no longer press the "Esc" key to dismiss the peek window. I just updated to Update 3 with the hope that it would be back, but it's not.

I've inspected the shortcuts and have not found one that makes Esc dismiss the peek window. My current work around is Shift+Tab, Esc; and that works but it is very cumbersome.

I read the Peek documentation at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx] but that says to use Esc, but Esc doesn't work anymore.

I've done much googling and binging and I have found no solution yet.

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the Snippetizer extension, and suddenly, Peek was dismisable using the Esc key